# Difference between a RAT and a hVNC

Tags: malware, apt, rat

What is the difference between a Remote Access Trojan and a hidden Virtual Network Computing?

It seems that both software allows a hacker to access a victim's computer and to spy on activity.

Answer (score 1):

A Remote Access Trojan (RAT) is a *category* of software. Lots of things can be RATs. Even hVNC.

hVNC is an *implementation* of VNC. One of the use cases is to use it as a RAT. But it can be used for other purposes, too.

Comment: My question could be "difference between Remote Access Trojan and hVNC" for more relevance.. So if we talk about RAT (T for Trojan), RAT is a trojan so it's malicious. RAT can be graphical like a hVNC or just simply under the form of a terminal. RAT includes a backdoor to give an access to an attacker and it offers to him different features for spying. I always thought  that a trojan is just a trap looking like a legitimate software and containing malicious paylod..

Comment: It's far more nuanced than that. RATs do not need to include backdoors. Backdoors mean that you can *return* to the target.

Comment: A RAT has to include a backdoor or at least a way to open a tunnel to exfiltrate desired informations.

Comment: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/RAT-remote-access-Trojan

Comment: I do not agree with that narrow definition. A backdoor implies persistence. I.E. that you can return at a later date. That's not a requirement for a RAT.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to understand what is concretely the exact definition of a Remote Access Trojan.

Comment: No, you've asked for the difference between RAT and hVNC. If your goal is to better understand RAT, then that's a separate issue.